# Get data from an array of stdClass object

Tags: php, api, object, vimeo, stdclass

I'm trying to retrieve the value of the field from the Vimeo Api, I've tried all possible solutions mentioned here. Can someone tell me how to retrieve the thumnail and url from the thumbnails and urls object respectively?

```
array(1) {
    [0]=>       
        stdClass Object (
            [allow_adds] => 1
            [embed_privacy] => anywhere
            [id] => 123456789
            [is_hd] => 0
            [is_transcoding] => 0
            [license] => 0
            [privacy] => anybody
            [title] => Soap Opera
            [description] => 
            [upload_date] => 2014-02-20 03:03:50
            [modified_date] => 2014-02-20 19:06:05
            [number_of_plays] => 1
            [number_of_likes] => 0
            [number_of_comments] => 0
            [width] => 600
            [height] => 480
            [duration] => 32
            [owner] => stdClass Object (
                [display_name] => blah
                [id] => 12345678
                [is_plus] => 0
                [is_pro] => 1
                [is_staff] => 0
                [profileurl] => http://vimeo.com/st
                [realname] => ST
                [username] => ST
                [videosurl] => http://vimeo.com/st/videos
                [portraits] => stdClass Object (
                    [portrait] => Array (
                        [0] => stdClass Object (
                            [height] => 30
                            [width] => 30
                            [_content] => http://b.vimeocdn.com/x.jpg
                        )

                        [1] => stdClass Object (
                            [height] => 75
                            [width] => 75
                            [_content] => http://b.vimeocdn.com/x.jpg
                        )

                        [2] => stdClass Object (
                            [height] => 100
                            [width] => 100
                            [_content] => http://b.vimeocdn.com/x.jpg
                        )

                        [3] => stdClass Object (
                            [height] => 300
                            [width] => 300
                            [_content] => http://b.vimeocdn.com/x.jpg
                        )

                    )

                )

            )

            [urls] => stdClass Object (
                [url] => Array (
                    [0] => stdClass Object (
                        [type] => video
                        [_content] => http://vimeo.com/0000
                    )
                )
            )

        [thumbnails] => stdClass Object (
            [thumbnail] => Array (
                [0] => stdClass Object (
                    [height] => 75
                    [width] => 100
                    [_content] => http://b.vimeocdn.com/x.jpg
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

I have an array **$vids** which has the meta info of various vids along with another call inside the loop which fetches the second array **$vidInfo** containing the array displayed above for each entry. I can retrieve the title etc just like I would access an object normally.
but I can't traverse any further the response above.

```
<?php 
     $vids = $videos->videos->video;    
         foreach ($vids as $vid){
             $id = $vid->id;
             $vidInfo = $vimeo->call('vimeo.videos.getInfo', array('video_id' => $id));
             $vidUrl = $vidInfo->video;  
             echo  $vid->title;
             echo '<br />';
             print_r($vidUrl->urls->url[0]->{'_content'});
             //echo '<pre>' . print_r($vidUrl) .  '</pre>'; 
         }
    ?>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: `$object->urls->url[0]->_content` is the URL, and `$object->thumbnails->thumbnail[0]->_content` is the thumbnail... what exactly did you find hard to get here ?

Comment: I've been trying that all day, along with other possible ways to access objects in arrays, but when I loop it and try to echo the url for each of the entries, it's returns null. Thank you so much for replying though. : ] it still won't return anything inside a foreach loop.

Comment: So show us what you've tried exactly (codewise) and we'll attempt to help you with that. This site is about learning to do things, not just to get a quick fix ;)

Comment: Haha @Tularis my bad for not giving more info and couldn't agree more, ok I'll post the code in the main post along with the link. I'm basically testing all this at http://ui-candy.com/vimeo/ : )

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `print_r($vidUrl[0]->urls->url[0]->_content);` instead? considering the first element is actually a value in an array (which happens to be an object)

Comment: @Tularis That was absolutely genius! Thank you soo much for pointing that out as well, that should help me get around nested objects in the future like a pro! :D I'll mark the below answer as correct, would help a lot of others starting out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering you have:

```
    [urls] => stdClass Object
    (
        [url] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [type] => video
                        [_content] => http://vimeo.com/0000
                    )

            )

    )
```

Accessing an object is done via the object-access-operator (`->`), while accessing an array is done via square brackets (`[x]`).
So you end up with `urls->url[0]->_content` in this case. Since `urls` is an object, and `url` is an array, whose first (`[0]`) index contains another object.

So in short, to answer your full original question:
`$object->urls->url[0]->_content` is the URL
and 
`$object->thumbnails->thumbnail[0]->_content` is the thumbnail

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response but I'm pretty comfortable traversing objects and arrays, having tried all sorts of combinations I've spent half the day, thinking I'm just moments away. :P

Comment: Cannot traverse any further than $object. not even $object->urls. Is there any reason for that, which you can think of? Another way would be converting the object to array and trying but I'm sure there are much better ways than that.

Answer (score 2):

For URL

```
echo $yourobj->urls->url[0]->{'_content'};
```

For Thumbnail

```
echo $yourobj->thumbnails->thumbnail[0]->{'_content'};
```

As you can see from the `print_r` representation, you can see `stdClass Object` and `Array` , so the former represents an `object` and the latter represents an `array`. Objects are accessed like `->` . For accessing array elements you use the square brackets `[ ]`

Comment: `->_content` is a prefectly normal and allowed identifier. No need to use `->{'_content'}` here...

Comment: Did I say anywhere that it is _abnormal_ ?

Comment: No, but I don't understand why you would use `{'_content'}` otherwise. Noone I know of uses it for non-exoctic property-names. By this answer it seems like you're advocating the use of it in all situations.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and your time @Shankar, trust me I've tried all sorts of combinations which include those two, to no avail. haha